# Is defining unnamed macros possible? ("lambda" macros?)

Tags: lambda, emacs, macros, elisp-macro

My goal is to evaluate an expression at compile time, like some simple things as (+ 1 1). But, I would like an integer "2" to be compiled in, instead of a full "1+1" operation to be done at runtime, without using a *named macro*. This makes my source code clearer showing how I got the value "2" while not wasting CPU time repeating the same "1+1" operation. Here is a simple example illustrating the basic idea but not for real cases, say, my ideal goal *defun* function looks like this:

```
(defun test ()
   (+ 1 2 3))
```

I would like literal "2" to be **evaluated at compile time** so I use *eval-when-compile*:

```
(defun test ()
   (+ 1 
      (eval-when-compile (+ 1 1)) 
      3))
```

However, it turns out becoming:

```
(defun test ()
   (+ 1 '2 3))
```

It's of course okay for this simple case but this extra *quote* is causing problems for more complicated cases.

Defining a **named macro** works:

```
(defmacro 1+1 () `,(+ 1 1))
(defun test ()
   (+ 1 (1+1) 3))
```

It will produce my ideal result with no *quote* prepending the integer "2":

```
(defun test ()
    (+ 1 2 3))
```

Is there a simple way like the above *eval-when-compile* to achieve this, *in a defun*? Something like an unnamed macro to get rid of the named helper *1+1*, or should I call this *"lambda macro"*?

Comment: Could you change the example to one which is actually demonstrating a problem?

Comment: Another simplified example like generating the documentation string for an elisp function: `(defun test() (eval-when-compile (concat "doc" "string")) (+ 1 2))` with `(documentation 'test)` we'll get "nil". The generated doc-string for function _test_ actaully becomes `'"docstring"` -- a quote prefixed the `"docstring"`.

Comment: Well you can't do that anyway.  If you want to specify a non-string docstring you need to use the symbol property.  Code which, if it did what you wanted, would *only* work when compiled, is also not a good example.

Comment: On the contrary, I **want** a string doc-string to be generated. My example _still_ shows how `eval-when-compile` would fail. However, a macro that precomputes `(concat "doc" "string")` could correctly generate a string doc-string `"docstring"` instead of the incorrect quoted "docstring" `'"docstring"`.

Comment: Yes, but for *uncompiled* elisp the docstring parameter of `defun` *must* be a string -- it cannot be some other form which simply evaluates to a string, because then it will not be seen as a docstring, and will instead become part of the BODY of the function, evaluated whenever it is called (which in principle might be anything between harmless and disastrous).  Again, if `eval-when-compile` worked the way you want it to work, your usage here would *only* work for byte-compiled code, which I think is a terrible goal that you shouldn't be aiming for.

Comment: Let me show you the rest of the example `(defmacro testdoc () \`,(concat "doc" "string")) (defun test () (testdoc) (+ 1 2))`. No matter byte-compile this or not, the `test` function has a correct "docstring" as its documentation. I am asking *if* there is a way to achieve this without a **named** macro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by the answer of @phils, I finally able to define anonymous macros and run them. I define a helper macro named **immediate** to help solving this; it basically defines an anonymous macro function temporarily using *macrolet*, then runs it:

```
(defmacro immediate (body)
  "Define an anonymous macro and run it immediately"
  (let ((f (make-symbol "immed")))
    `(macrolet ((,f () ,body))
       (,f))))
```

With *immediate*, I can rewrite the sample code in my original question this way:

```
(defun test ()
  (immediate (concat "Docstring" " of " "test" ))
  (+ 1
     (immediate (+ 1 1))
     3))
```

The *test* function will be defined exactly as what I expected it to be:

```
(defun test ()
  "Docstring of test"
  (+ 1 2 3))
```

(The name *immediate* is inspired by the *immediate words* from the **Forth** language.)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a way to create *anonymous* macros, but `macrolet` facilitates a temporary scope for named macros, which you could use like so:

```el
(defun foo ()
  (macrolet ((docstring () (concat "foo" "bar")))
    (docstring))
  'foo)
```

Note that if this is *genuinely* just for docstrings, you could instead do this:

```el
(defun foo () 'foo)
(put 'foo 'function-documentation (concat "foo" "bar"))
```

Comment: That's it! **macrolet** is the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are thinking about constant folding. It is no requirement to do so, but the fastest compilers does it. Here is an example from SBCL:

```
* (defun test () (+ 1 2 3))

TEST
* (disassemble #'test)

; disassembly for TEST
; Size: 22 bytes. Origin: #x100189010C
; 0C:       498B4D60         MOV RCX, [R13+96]                ; no-arg-parsing entry point
                                                              ; thread.binding-stack-pointer
; 10:       48894DF8         MOV [RBP-8], RCX
; 14:       BA0C000000       MOV EDX, 12
; 19:       488BE5           MOV RSP, RBP
; 1C:       F8               CLC
; 1D:       5D               POP RBP
; 1E:       C3               RET
; 1F:       0F0B0F           BREAK 15                         ; Invalid argument count trap
NIL
```

You see no additions done, but you see the constant `12` which is the pointer address for the fixnum `6`

Here in CLISP:

```
[2]> (disassemble #'test)

Disassembly of function test
(CONST 0) = 6
0 required arguments
0 optional arguments
No rest parameter
No keyword parameters
2 byte-code instructions:
0     (const 0)                           ; 6
1     (skip&ret 1)
nil
```

Thus from this if you use a modern Common Lisp implementation which isn't someones attempt at comedy you should not need to think about these matters.

Comment: Thanks, but my example is just a simplified case showing the idea, not just for constant folding. The result could be a string, a list or something else. I modified my question a bit accordingly.

Comment: @Sylwester, FYI elisp is no different in this scenario.  You can update your answer with: `(disassemble
     (byte-compile
      '(defun test ()
         (+ 1
            (eval-when-compile (+ 1 1))
            3))))`